# How to access variable from a python function using qweb

Tags: report, odoo, qweb, odoo-14

How can I access the variable from a function? For example:

```
def get_data(self):
    var = "I am a variable"
```

Then I would like to get the data of `var` from that function and put it to my report.
And this is what I did:

```
<span t-esc"o.get_data(var)"/>
```

But I am facing an error like `TypeError: get_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.`

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I just got the answer.
I just put a return to `var`.

```
def get_data(self):
    var = "I am a variable"
    return var
```

then put this on a report:
`<span t-esc="o.get_data()/>`

Answer (score 0):

you can also pass the params in xml,

```
<span t-esc="o.get_data(a)/>
```

and in python

```
def get_data(self, a):
    name = a
    return name
```